# Facing error in plsql procedure while using if else

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql

I have included a snippet from my plsql procedure. In this I have an if else if lock.I am doing a string comparison in IF which is not giving an error and another string comparison in ELSE IF which is highlighted in red and giving an error.
I am unable to understand why.

```
IF x='new' THEN
   --sql statement

ELSEIF x='old' THEN
   --sql statement
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for else if is `elsif` not `elseif`, without the 'e'.

Comment: Oh didn't know that my code compiled after this change Thanks alot!